# Unable to send request to the grafana using basic authentication

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, grafana, basic-authentication, grafana-api

I'm using Grafana free version (v8.5.0). I'm using python 3.7 and sending requests to Grafana. But it is not working. Below is my Code.

```
import requests

import json

base_url="https://MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD@santoshburadalearning.grafana.net"

resp = requests.get(base_url+"/app/dashboards/home", verify=True)

data = resp.json()

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'message':'invalid username or password', 'traceId':'1710926f6a9a7120'}
```

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Did you validate, that the username and password, that you are sending, are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are valid credentials

Comment: You should get a tutorial from grafana. What you're trying to do is so basic that they should have a working code example.

Comment: I referred the doc. Unable to find anything, can you help me?

Comment: I don't know grafana, sorry. The python side of your code looks all right.

Comment: The error message looks from Grafana when `auth_basic` enabled in `nginx.conf`. Check this > https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220092/grafana-returns-401-unauthorized-when-accessed-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

base_url="https://santoshburadalearning.grafana.net"

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('MY_USERNAME', 'MY_PASSWORD')
resp = s.get(base_url+ "/api/search/", verify=False)
data = resp.json()

print(data)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76234417/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).