# Grafana returns 401 Unauthorized when accessed behind a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, grafana

I run Grafana with a custom root url behind an Nginx reverse proxy, based on what is shown at https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/ but when i try to access site.com/grafana, i get a 401 unauthorized with the following json response :

```
{"message":"invalid username or password","traceID":""}
```

i have tried multiple nginx and docker setups but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an nginx auth_basic issue, i don't know why, but i never encountered this issue with any other app.
Basically, auth_basic login and password are proxied to grafana, and there are no possibilities to try other logins.
To solve this i had to set

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "";
```

in nginx conf and voilà

Comment: Dang. That didn't work for me.

Comment: In my env, there are `auth_basic`, `reverse_proxy` and `upstream`. The issue occurs when `auth_basic` gets enabled and gone when disabled. Adding `proxy_set_header Authorization "";` in `nginx.conf` resolves this issue.